# Openlayers TypeError: a.geometry.getBounds is not a function

Tags: openlayers

I am getting an error in Openlayers.js file as mentioned below:

```
"TypeError: a.geometry.getBounds is not a function"
[Break On This Error]   

...=this.resolution||this.map.getResolution()},drawFeature:function(a,b){null==b&&(...
```

If anybody know the solution please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

How do you add your feature to the layer.

I had the same problem today and found the solution.

The error occured when I did this:

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.LatLon(lat, lng);
```

The fix was changing the LatLon to Point like this:

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lat, lng));
```